# Readfile ends after found a space between characters

Tags: visual-c++

My code here reads a path from a file, modify it (putting extra backward slash, when if founds a backward slash), and write it back to another file. But the result is a little error.

example run:

textfile A  -->  `c:\program files\work\exe`

textfile B  -->  `c:\\program`

The result that I expect to be at textfile B is like this:

textfile A  -->  `c:\\program files\\work\\exe`

```
//read path data from text file 
char str[256];
fstream file_op("C:\\PROGRA~1\\logdata",ios::in);
file_op >> str;
file_op.close();

char newPath[MAX_PATH];
int newCount = 0;
for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
 if(str[i] == '\\')
   {
    newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
   }
   newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
}
newPath[newCount]=0;
ofstream out("c:\\path.txt", ios::out | ios::out);
out.write(newPath, strlen(newPath));
out.close();
```

Comment: solved. I used this-- > file_op.getline(str, 256);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: `file_op >> str;`  That will read characters up to (but not including) any white space and put them in the string.  If you would put it in a loop, you would find that you'd get the next "word", but the white space would be skipped.

But there is another way.  Assuming that the path is on one line, you could do:

```
std::getline(file_op, str)
```

This will read an entire line into `str`.

Comment: after compile, I got this error: Error 4 error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided c:\work\b.cpp

Comment: Strange, there should be a two argument version.  Anyway, the third argument is a delimiter character, which, if you're splitting by lines, should be '\n'.  The full thing would be: `std::getline(file_op, str, '\n')`. Hopefully that works.

Comment: modified it by putting the delimiter. but got this error: Error 5 error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'char [256]' c:\work\b.cpp

Comment: I see what I did wrong: `std::getline` takes a `std:string` argument, and for some reason I didn't see that you were using a `char*` argument.  My mistake.